# Trigger to update table based on another table update in mysql

Tags: mysql, sql, triggers

I have two tables 
**1.** Tag
**2.** Triger_testing

**Tag desc** 
 *id int, is_active (tinyint)*

**Trigger_Testing Desc** 
 *tag_id (int), is_active(tinyint)*

I want to create a trigger on **tag** table update which update **trigger_testing** table. So if ***tag.is_active is set to 0*** the trigger must fire and update trigger_testing table and ***set trigger_testing.is_active=0 where trigger_testing.tag_id=tag.id***.

I tried to create a trigger in MYSQL but getting syntax exception. Can someone help me out in resolving that issue.

Here is the code : -

```
CREATE TRIGGER update_trigger_testing AFTER UPDATE ON tag 
FOR EACH ROW
 BEGIN
    IF NEW.is_active=0 THEN
       UPDATE trigger_testing SET is_Active=0 WHERE tag_id=NEW.id   
    END IF
END$$

DELIMITER;
```

The error I am getting is :

***Error Code: 1064
You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'END IF
END$$
DELIMITER' at line 6***

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
CREATE TRIGGER update_trigger_testing AFTER UPDATE ON tag 
FOR EACH ROW
 BEGIN
    IF NEW.is_active=0 THEN
       UPDATE trigger_testing SET is_Active=0 WHERE tag_id=NEW.id;   
    END IF;
END;
```

Comment: Thanks for answer, I just found the solution as well, I was missing semicolon after update statement;